# How to lock Solaris 10 in the shell

Tags: solaris, shell, gnome

How can I lock the screen via the shell?

System:

- Solaris 10
- GNOME desktop environment

For some reason Launch > Lock Screen does not work. A fix for that would also be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After reading @egorgry's answer, I tried `xlock` randomly. I figured `xset` worked, and lock is what I'm trying to achieve so why not try `xlock`? It worked!

So for future reference:

The `xlock` command locks your screen.

Comment: does this solve the issue with locking from the gui? if you enable it in xset it should work from the gui too. I don't have solaris to play with right now.

Answer (score 0):

Is the system using the gnome screen saver?

If it is then you can do this:

```
$ gnome-screensaver-command --lock
```

Comment: not a recognized command

Answer (score 0):

use xset -q to see if locking is enabled or disabled. read the xset man to see how to change these settings. I hope this helps you.